# VB.net textbox return hit(enter) event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to catch return hit (enter) on TextBox?

The following does not work. I am keep getting error "KeyPress event can't be found".

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox.KeyPress
        If TextBox.Text Is Nothing Then Return
        If TextBox.Text.Length = 6 And Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
            ' Do something here
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of Asc(e.KeyChar)?

Comment: @PreetSangha - http://snippi.com/s/tha42c5 - in our case we check if the Asc  = 13 (enter)

Comment: I mean what value do you get when you debug it?

Comment: @PreetSangha  Application never gets loaded - I am keep getting error "KeyPress event can't be found".

Comment: You can't use win forms' `KeyPress` event in asp.net, what you want to do on key press ?

Comment: @Coder - run another subroutine

Comment: go to the text box properties and make sure the KeyPress event is pointing to the right function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does work:

```
Private Sub TextBox_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As Integer)

        If TextBox.Text Is Nothing Then Return
        If TextBox.Text.Length = 6 And KeyAscii = 13 Then
            ' Do something here
        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try deleting the text box and re-entering the code

```
If TextBox.Text Is Nothing Then Return
    If TextBox.Text.Length = 6 And Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
        ' Do something here
    End If
```

as that should work - you most likely have something messed up with the textbox name or keypress declaration code.

I just checked that code in a new text box and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(13) Then
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim <> Nothing Then
            'Do Something here
        End If
    End If
```